# a.out linux executable is of which program?

Tags: c++, c, executable

Given a current directory with lots of files and let's say I compiled one file and generated executable **a.out**. Now, I want to find from which program this executable has been generated.
How, can I do it?

Comment: Generally: you can't.

Comment: What do you mean by program? source code?

Comment: I think he would like to link source and the executable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `readelf`:

```
readelf -a a.out | grep FILE
```

For instance:

```
$ gcc t.c
$ readelf -a a.out |grep FILE
    28: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    36: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS crtstuff.c
    41: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS t.c
$
```

Alternatively, you can use

```
objdump -t a.out |grep df
```

Example:

```
$ objdump -t a.out |grep df
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              crtstuff.c
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              crtstuff.c
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000              t.c
```

Comment: +1.  Although, it wouldn't (obviously) work when you say: `echo "int main() {}" | gcc -x c - -o - | xargs readelf -a - | grep FILE`

Comment: Indeed I assumed the executable was compiled from an actual file, given the OP's problem description.

Comment: I was _kidding_, wasn't I?

Comment: @devnull Ok, my bad. Given the absence of visual clue indicating otherwise, I was fooled into thinking you were picky. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `objdump`:

```
> objdump -g a.exe

a.exe:     file format pei-i386

crt1.c:
cygming-crtbegin.c:
file.c:
tlssup.c:
CRTglob.c:
CRTfmode.c:
txtmode.c:
CRT_fp10.c:
cpu_features.c:
...
```

Comment: Does this need `a.exe`to be compiled with debugging enabled? (`-g`)

Comment: @damienfrancois Yes, the presence of `-g` _implies_ that.